# SQL Server Unique Constraint on two columns with an exception

Tags: sql-server, database-design, trigger, unique-constraint

Hi all and thanks for your advice.

Expense(SupplierID(Foreign Key), DocumentID(vchar))

I understand how to add a simple unique constraint on two columns.  However, if DocumentID = 'NA', I would like to ignore the rules of the constraint.

Some suppliers in our system do not provide an invoice id, for example.  Therefore, I leave the field NULL.  I would like to remove all nulls for the field 'DocumentID' to avoid accounting for the NULLS in my client code.

I am new to SQL Server, but I could figure out how to do this using a trigger.  The reason I'm asking here is to see if there is a better way to respond to this scenario or to avoid it by a different design.

Thanks!

Thanks Tibor.  I was unable to enter a comment correctly, I suppose.  This is what I ended up with using your method.

```
use CMRBE  
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_SupplierID_DocumentID  
ON Expense(SupplierID, DocumentID)  
WHERE DocumentID <> 'NA';
```

Comment: I highly recommend `<>` over `!=` - https://sqlblog.org/2008/03/20/which-to-use-or

Comment: @Aaron Thank you Aaron.  I read the article.  Thanks!.  Will be using <> as I am comfortable with either.

Comment: A bit of time travel there, referring to Aaron's blog post. :-) Still valid, though. Tom, did the index solve your problem?

Comment: Please, please re-post your solution as an answer and remove it from the question, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a unique index with a where clause to filter out those values for which you want to avoid duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Tibor.  This is what I ended up with and it fits the bill.

```
use CMRBE  
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_SupplierID_DocumentID  
ON Expense(SupplierID, DocumentID)  
WHERE DocumentID <> 'NA';
```